# It is possible to edit a question to make it completely blank?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, questions, character-limit

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461819/  <-- This question has been deleted.

The question was edited so that the title and body were blank.

Edit:

As Brandon [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23158/377968), this was accomplished by editing the question to all spaces. I suggest we start enforcing the character limit (by ignoring white space). I agree that the 15 character limit for comments is a nuisance, so I also suggest this be shortened (maybe all the way to 1 character).

This bug has already been documented. However, I believe the question I referenced above demonstrates a unique effect of this bug so I wouldn't consider this post to be a dupe.

Comment: I consider this post to be a dupe. Please add your point to the original question.

Comment: I had deleted that question before I came here and saw this.  Sorry to anyone who can't see the page that's linked to, but the devs can see it, so there's enough information here for them to process the bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

It is. It's not actually blank; it consists of spaces which lets it bypass the character limit. It's a known "bug", but it's a bug that most of the community likes.

Comment: Bypassing the min character limit is one thing - but no title and no body is pretty extreme.

Comment: I agree, but if you look at the edits, thats how it was done. Most people like it for the fact that you don't have to enter 15 characters for a comment, but for a question a character limit should really be enforced.

Comment: If we don't like the limit, maybe the limit should simply be changed.

Comment: I guess that the limit is there for new comers, that are, in theory, more likely to misbehave.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, any empty posts are easily removed ;-p I can't say I've seen this hugely, so I can't say it is much of an *actual* problem. Most of the time.

Should it be "fixed"? probably; is it pressingly urgent? probably not.