# How did this question manage to get added without a title?

Tags: bug, status-completed, character-limit

Came across this question today that didn't have a title and thus nothing to click in the question view to open it. However, clicking the vote count seemed to work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466407/

Seems like at a minimum it should show a generic title like "(Untitled Question)"

Possible bug?

Comment: Sorry for the dupe question of (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/it-is-possible-to-edit-a-question-to-make-it-completely-blank). Didn't find that one in my search because I didn't realize it was an editing issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way: you can create a question, submit, click edit, delete the title and all the text, and leave nothing but 15 characters in its place.

If you do that in under 5 minutes, there will be no revision history.

Comment: Wow. You really know your StackExchange!

Answer (score 4):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

Enjoy.

Comment: umpteen bajillion. But the question list only shows roughly 4.500 questions. Call the waffle squad!

Comment: lol.  The squeeky wheel gets the grease.  Now we just need an umpteen bajillion bugs on [insert favorite feature-request here]!

Answer (score 2):

The title and contents were probably removed in an edit, after posting, because they were very inflammatory.